# TypeScript Heisenbug driving me crazy: Excluding types with control statements

Tags: typescript

I simplified an error I was getting to a base case that *sometimes* reproduces on the TypeScript Playground, but usually it needs to be poked to be reproduced. It fails every time for me locally when running `tsc`.

```
type Result = {
  success: true,
  value: string,
} | {
  success: false,
  error: string,
};

const x = {success: true, value: 'hello'} as Result;
if (!x.success) {
  console.log(x.error);
}
```

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?moduleResolution=99&module=1&jsx=0&isolatedModules=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvAUFKSAxoQvAFxTABOiEANHlAG4CGytF81AlgHYDmDAL5QAPtkZES8clABmbePUYQqVAPZVOPAcIDcOHIXW8uUAB4ZsU0hWq06zNhygByABYRkyda5Et4WAQUYANuOSgACgBCcwA6GxkASgl8Y1N1ZAg4n35I+NUNKiSDISA)

If you don't see an error on TypeScript Playground, click [TS Config] > and change Target. It doesn't seem to matter what I change it to. Change it to "ES2017" or "ES2019". This seems to trigger the error for me.

[image]

Questions:

(1) Is there something wrong with the approach in the code or should TypeScript be handling it?

(2) Is there a decent workaround (short of casting directly everywhere)?

Comment: While I can reproduce it, it is fixed with a refresh. Is this an actual problem in your production code?

Comment: @AlexWayne Yes, it fails every time locally when running `tsc`. (It shows an error sometimes but not always in VSCode.)

Comment: Yeah this is *definitely* worth filing an [issue in the TS GitHub repo](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues) (unless there's already one, but I haven't found it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript does not appear to be properly narrowing based off of the `!` operator. If you do a direct comparison against the value from your union, it works ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&moduleResolution=99&module=1&jsx=0&isolatedModules=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvAUFKSAxoQvAFxTABOiEANHlAG4CGytF81AlgHYDmDAL5QAPtkZES8clABmbePUYQqVAPZVOPAcIDcOHIXW8uUAB4ZsU0hWq06zNhygByABYRkyda5Et4WAQUYANuOSgACnMAOhsZDHRMBWQlAEoJfGNTdWQIGJ9+aJjVDSo0gyEgA)):

```
type Result = {
  success: true,
  value: string,
} | {
  success: false,
  error: string,
};

const x = {success: true, value: 'hello'} as Result;
if (x.success === false) {
  console.log(x.error);
}
```

This is surprising to me, and, based on the inconsistent results, it may be worth filing a [TypeScript repo issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues).

Comment: I hadn't tried comparing directly with `===`, and that is a much nicer workaround than explicitly casting. Thank!